# Does time in menus count for total completion time?

Tags: metroid-dread

Some unlocks in Metroid Dread require beating the game within a certain amount of time. Do these unlock requirements count time spent in menus? For example, if I pause the game and look at the map for two minutes, does that add two minutes to my final completion time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've speedrun the game in both Normal and Hard, and I can confirm that the pause menu does not add to the timer.

For my first run (Normal), I was watching someone else speedrun through the game on YouTube while replaying what I saw on my Switch. During the entire time I was watching the YouTube speedrun, I had the game paused. I still ended up getting a better time than the one on the YouTube video. If the pause menu added to the timer, I would've had roughly twice the time instead.

For my second run (Hard), I played purely from memory. I only paused the game to see where I needed to go and plan my route in advance. Despite spending very little time in the pause menu, I still got a very similar (albeit slightly longer) time compared to my normal run.

I've also seen various comments supporting the theory that the pause menu does not affect the timer, such as [this thread on GameFAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/323656-metroid-dread/79707891):

> Pausing stops the timer, and dying resets you to the checkpoint timer. Cutscenes are included in the timer even if you skip them.